# How can I create a json object from 3 different arrays in angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have 3 different arrays, one with column names of a table and the other with data.
How can I combine them to form one single json object in AngularJS?

```
var keyArray = ["Col1","Col2","Col3",...];
var ValArray1 = ["v1.1","v1.2","v1.3",...];
var ValArray2 = ["v2.1","v2.2","v2.3",...];
```

I want a json something like this

```
entries[
{
name: "Col1",
value: "v1.1" 
},
{name: "Col2",
value: "v1.2" 
},
...,
{name: "Col3",
value: "v2.3" 
}
]
```

Comment: it is not completely clear how you need to mix the keyArray with the two ValArrays.. you want just one object, first with the objects from, combination of keyArray with ValArray1 and then the  objects from combination of keyArray with ValArray2 ?

Comment: Yes. The first array contains the column names of a table and the other contain data.

Comment: but this could be merely a javascript question, you don't need angularjs at all.

Comment: sorry my bad. I want it like this

Comment: {
Col1:"v1.1" 
},
{
Col2:"v1.2" 
},
...,
{
Col3:"v2.3" 
}

Comment: edit your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this ok for you ? You don't need angularjs at all.

```
var addToArray = function(entries, keys, values){
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        if(keys[i] && values[i]) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[keys[i]] =   values[i];            
            entries.push(obj);
        }
    }
}

var entries = [];
addToArray(entries, keyArray, ValArray1);
addToArray(entries, keyArray, ValArray2);
```

if you want to use something from angular, you could use `angular.forEach` instead

This will mix keys with array one, and then keys with array two.. I did it in that way because in your question is not clearly stated when it should stop using array one and start using array two (after you use all the values in array two, maybe ?)

anyway, for your purpose I think the key point is

```
obj[keys[i]] =   values[i];
```

This will let you create a property name with the string in your array

Answer (score 0):

How about
    entries = { "Col1" : "v1.1", "Col2" : "v1.2", "Col3" : "v2.3" }
So you can access it as
    entries[Col1] which is v1.1